# CloneZilla errors when attempting to clone and create partition table proportionally

Tags: partitioning, mbr, clone, clonezilla

Carrying on from a [question regarding hard drive space](https://superuser.com/questions/561269/lost-hard-drive-space-after-clone/561285#comment684330_561285) on a cloned hard drive, i'm attempting to recover the space using CloneZilla and using the setting -k1, create partition table proportionally. I'm getting errors which stop me from completing the clone:

> /tmp/ocs_onthefly_local.KhmwWk/tgt_pt.parted was not found! It is
>   required so that we know the original disk size! Maybe your Clonezilla
>   image is too old? You can try to create such a file in your source
>   machine by: "parted -s /dev/ unit s print >
>   /tmp/ocs_onthefly_local.KhmwWk/tgt_pt.parted" (Replace with your
>   device name) Program terminated!!

That is then followed by:

> Do you want to clone the boot loader (executable code area, the first
>   446 bytes) to: sdc? y/n

I press 'y' and proceed and the cloning process begins. After a while it completes but when I go to boot from the new clone i get

> No boot sector found on internal drive

I'd like to be able to resolve this issue but if there's an easier way to recover my hard drive space that'd be all the better.

Comment: What options are you using to save the image?

Comment: @Kyle Sorry for the delay. The options i chose were...Device-Device -> Expert mode -> Kept the defaults -> Selected -k1 -> Disk to local disk -> Skip checking. Maybe not necessarily in that order, I can't recall the exact order

Comment: Would saving the device-image then restoring the image be possible for you? You can save it to a network location via the samba share options if that's easier. It looks like clonezilla is having an issue with the temporary copy of the image.

Comment: @Kyle I'm afraid not, I don't have 80GB of hard drive space free elsewhere. It's kind of worrying that I have this brand new 128GB SSD and I don't seem to be able to recover the 'hidden' 40GB

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla wrote the partition table to the wrong file: It uses tgt-pt.parted instead of tgt_pt.parted SO it can't find the file.